# How to use animations on a rigid body not kinematic?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, rigid-bodies

I have no experience with animations and am trying to insert animations on a character that I move with AddForce.
If I insert the walking animation, the animation moves the rigid body and she decides the speed at which it moves. If in the animator I do not apply "Root Motion" the animation does not move the character and I can move it with AddForce, but the animation is not in sync with the speed of the character.
How can I connect the speed of the animation to that with which I move the rigid body. I wish that if I change my "speed" parameter that I use to move the character, the speed of the animation also changes, always keeping in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be work for you:

```
float speed;//you must set this value with rigidbody's velocity
Animator animator;
void Start()
{
    animator=getComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    animator.speed=speed;//you can change it with speed/10 to make more realistic
}
```